# Why different behavior while making AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, xmlhttprequest, query-string

In Javascript, I am making a normal AJAX call using XMLHttpRequest as given below

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
url = "my_append_params?x=3";
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    //....code...
}
xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xhttp.send();
```

I am seeing 2 behaviors while making the same call on 2 different pages. The 2 scenarios are -

Scenario 1) In page 'www.abc.com/mydetails/', I am making above AJAX call, and the network tab says the call made is for url -'www.abc.com/mydetails/my_append_params?x=3'

Scenario 2) In page 'www.xyz.com/mydetails/', while making the AJAX call, the network tab says the call made is for url -
'www.xyz.com/my_append_params?x=3' //('mydetails' taken off from url)

I got to know what is actually happening.
In scenario 1, the page does not have a 'base' tag.
while in scenario 2, there is a base tag and href set to 'www.xyz.com/'

So Requirement -
I want to have in scenario 1, the behavior of scneario 2. ie, i cannot add base tag for abc.com, yet want to have it pick the base url only. Any help?

Comment: That won't happen with the page origins you've shown in your question, the second scenario will not make the query you've described. I'm afraid we can't help you without more accurate information. (Now, if the page origin in scenario 2 were `www.xyz.com/mydetails` rather than `www.xyz.com/mydetails/`, that would be different.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Can you share any resource where I can read about this. And if you could tell me how it would be different with and without "/" at the end

Comment: Just search for "relative url" resources. The `/` at the end is significant because `http://example.com/foo` + `page.html` is `http://example.com/page.html`, but `http://example.com/foo/` (with the trailing `/`) + `page.html` is `http://example.com/foo/page.html`.